# Finding Volume Label of a usb mass storage device using python

Tags: usb, python

Could someone please tell me how I could obtain a usb mass storage device's volume label(the name displayed in the explorer, not the device name::/dev/sdX) using python?
libraries/modules though HAL has deprecated so please don't suggest it as an option.

Comment: The volume labels could be read from the `/dev/disk/by-label/` directory, but it seems that it doesn't exist on all systems. The `blkid` command should also print volume labels, but it needs superuser privileges.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @SylvainPineau my bad.

Comment: @Vineet Kaushik, no problem. You can also vote on answers by cliking on the `^` symbol.

Comment: @SylvainPineau yep just did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query UDisks2 using the dbus API from python:

Install python-dbus:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dbus
```

Run this small python snippet:

```
cat <<EOF | python -
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks2', '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2')
om = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')
for k,v in om.GetManagedObjects().iteritems():
    drive_info = v.get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive', {})
    if drive_info.get('ConnectionBus') == 'usb' and drive_info.get('Removable'):
        print("Device Label: %s" % drive_info['Id'])
EOF
```

With a USB drive attached I get:

```
Device Label: Generic-Flash-Disk-EEA1EE5B
```

Comment: I had asked for the device name as seen in the explorer...such as ABC if I name my device ABC. Is there a list of info that can be queried using UDisk?

Comment: The drive info properties are available [here](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive.html)

Comment: And all the interfaces that you can query: http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/ch02.html